# OpenCV Video module tutorials

Tags: c++, opencv, computer-vision, video-processing

As you know there is no opencv official tutorial for video module. That tutorial section is empty. I googled but couldn't find anything good. Any of you know a good OpenCV video module tutorial in c++?

Actually, I need to capture humans, then identify the colour of their T-Shirts

Comment: Google result from `OpenCV video` has many useful links on first page...

Answer (score 2):

you just want to capture video stream or apply some algo on it or what?

check this

http://www.cc.gatech.edu/~daleshin/OpenCV_Tutorial.pdf

Comment: Hi, please have a look at my question again. I edited it with the information you requested

Answer (score 2):

Here is a small example on opencv docs to capture from cam.

http://docs.opencv.org/modules/highgui/doc/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this help you to detect peoples 
http://docs.opencv.org/modules/gpu/doc/object_detection.html

Answer (score 1):

These books from opencv.org may be useful for you
http://opencv.org/books.html

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using haarcascade xml already provided in opencv.

Then you can check the color of t-shirt by applying simple opencv filters to extract color.

Haarcascade xmls are available of full human body, upper half, lower half etc.